# Android Calendar between dates

Tags: android, date, if-statement, calendar, dialog

I currently have an application which allows a user to select a date. When the user selects my edit text box it display a calendar, when they select a date it is then shown in the edit text field. What I want to do is change the text within my textview when a particular date has been chosen or if its between a selection of dates.

Here is my question

Currently my edit text only selects a date and display its but does nothing with the information.

I want a textview to change to closed when the user selects any dates between 5th June - 30th June every year when a button is pressed and the remaining of the time say open. How would I go about adding this calendar function into my application?

My current setup

My Date Dialog

```
public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


EditText txtDate;

public DateDialog(View view){

    txtDate = (EditText)view;




}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);

}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    String date=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
    txtDate.setText(date);

}
}
```

---

// Allows the user to select a date for there stay at the vineyard

```
        txtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){

            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtDate.getWindowToken(), 0);


            DateDialog dialog = new DateDialog(v);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");


            im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtDate.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    });
```

Any help or guidance on the subject would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
String date=(month+1)+day;
int dateInt=Integer.parseValue(date);
if(dateInt<=0630 && dateInt>=0605)
  //Close
else
  //Open
```

**The approach that I use**

Here's the code that I usually use to create a DatePickerDialog and set the date to my fragment's textView. Use this on your textView's onClickListener:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity().getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        String date=(monthOfYear+1)+dayOfMonth;
                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
                        int dateInt = Integer.parseValue(date);
                        if(dateInt<=0630 && dateInt>=0605)
                          //Close
                        else
                          //Open

                    }
                },2016,05, 15);
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have one quick question, I currently have two classes set up one for date dialog and the other which is my fragment which you can see the txtDate onclicklistener. I want to contain your code on the same class as my txtdate and not on the date dialog, if you get what I mean?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but you should give it try: String date = (dialog.getDatePicker().getMonth()+1)+dialog.getDatePicker().getDayOfMonth();

Comment: Sadly I cannot get it to work but it was worth a try :D Recommend any new ways I can get around my situation even if it does mean starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your example, I know I'm being a pain but do you have a github program I can download.

Comment: Uhh, not yet.. But I can surely upload a Sample App for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed that I made a few mistakes on the code above. Here's an working sample app https://github.com/rosariopfernandes/datepickersampleapp